# Android BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...) doesn't load HTTPS URL on emulator

Tags: android

App doesn't load an Image from an HTTPS URL when run on the emulator.

Sample code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://someserver.com/photo.jpg");
mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream()));
```

The image loads just fine when run on an actual device. Also the emulator loads the image if it's accessed via HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue?

Comment: Try this:
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @AkashG Same result. Doesn't load the image when used with HTTPS.

Comment: @tamsler check answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241137/inputstream-read-has-no-response-when-downloading-large-imagesize-300k/11241660#11241660

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code for display image in imageview from url.

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView1);

URL url = new URL(address);
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

And also use below code for that.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Log.e("log", "bad url", t);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("log", "io error", t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a trusted https site? If not you will have a problem  with the connection.

Take a look at this...

http://droidos-coding.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-trusting-all-https-self-signed.html

Comment: Yes it's a trusted https site. Meaning they are using "real" SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(LoadImageFromWebOperations(url));

private Bitmap LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url){
           try{
             String encodedurl = url.replace(" ", "%20");
             InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(encodedurl).getContent();
             Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
             return d;
           }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//          System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
           }
         }
```

And pls make sure u have added **internet permission** in your manifest file.
This will help u to do so.

Comment: I have just tried your solution with no luck. It seems to be an issue with AVD (emulator) Android v2.2. The images show up correctly on 4.x based emulators as well as physical devices.