# BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String imagePath) returns null even image exists

Tags: android, image, bitmapfactory

I don't know , why I am getting null from BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String imagePath) method.
imagePath is perfect.Code is below here .

```
public static byte[] imageToByteArray(String imagePath){
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG , 100 , byteArrayOutputStream);
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

imaagePath is a internet specific path .Here I am using google place api and imagePath is location of image given by google web service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372831/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-doesnt-load-https-url-on-emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) is use to get `Bitmap` from local File system.

```
Decode a file path into a bitmap. If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null.
```

To get `Bitmap` from internet use

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Do not forget to run above line in background thread.

Comment: awesome. You helped me again

Comment: 1 more question @Mohsin.
I am getting following error while trying to post an image on facebook wall.

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload","type":"Exception"}}

pls help me.